# jQuery inserting double quotes

Tags: jquery

I have this simple jQuery code:

```
$("p").html("A simple <strong>example</strong>");
```

And when I inspect this using Chrome, I get:

```
<p>
  "A simple "
  <strong>example</strong>
</p>
```

Why are there double quotes here? Why don't I simply get:

```
<p>A simple </strong>example</strong></p>
```

Comment: How is it showing in browser, that might be chrome developer tool specific.

Comment: When the element is focused in the inspector, press F2.
This will convert the element into editable HTML, and you should not see the quotes anymore.

Answer (score 3):

This is just on chrome developer tool's reflection. If you check the html page source, you should not see this double quotas. try and share with us please.

Comment: But there's no way to check the source (CTRL+U) because the text is being added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

try using `.append()`

```
$("p").append("A simple <strong>example</strong>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .html() why dont you try .text() ? I think it fits better.